# How to join 3 tables on same primary key?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table. The tables is like this :

table hotel

```
id(pk)
hotel_code
hotel_name
hotel_address
```

table hotel_description

```
id(pk)
hotel_id(fk from table hotel)
hotel_title
hotel_description
```

table hotel_image

```
id(pk)
hotel_id(fk from table hotel)
image_title
image_description
```

My query to join 3 table is like this :

```
SELECT a.hotel_code, a.hotel_name, a.address, b.hotel_title, b.hotel_description, c.image_title, c.image_url
FROM hotel a
JOIN hotel_description b ON a.id = b.hotel_id
JOIN hotel_image c ON a.id = c.hotel_id
WHERE a.hotel_code = 'IDJKT_00001'
```

The result of run query above is like this :
http://snag.gy/nw541.jpg

It looked double data

How to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected data format ?

Comment: i am not sure, i think something is missing between `b` and `c`, try add this to the `where` clause `AND b.hotel_id = c.hotel_id` ?

Comment: @Yazan, `SELECT a.hotel_code, a.hotel_name, b.hotel_title, b.hotel_description, c.image_title, c.image_url
FROM hotel a
JOIN hotel_description b ON a.id = b.hotel_id
JOIN hotel_image c ON a.id = c.hotel_id
WHERE a.hotel_code = 'IDJKT_00001' AND b.hotel_id = c.hotel_id`. Like that? The result is the same

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman, I want not double data

Comment: yes, thats what i meant, sorry have no more ideas :(

Comment: actually i think adding `GROUP BY b.hotel_description` will fix this but i am not sure if it's correct, i mean there could be some mistake and group by is not the proper way to solve this, but you can give it a try!

Comment: Before you try to fix this problem i'd ask you what is the relation between these tables. if they have a `one to one` relation it's better to just combine it into one table, it's much cleaner and you can set certain columns so that they may be left empty.  If you don't want to do that could you turn this into an sql fiddle that would help us greatly in being able to experiment and pinpoint the problem http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @RyanVincent, hotel_code is unique

Comment: i mean the id not hotel_code

Answer (score 0):

There is no double data, you have multiple descriptions for your hotel and you have multiple images for your hotel, you would have to request these in 3 seperate queries if you don't want them to show up more than once:

```
SELECT a.hotel_code, a.hotel_name, a.address
FROM hotel a
WHERE a.hotel_code = 'IDJKT_00001'

SELECT b.hotel_title, b.hotel_description
FROM hotel a
JOIN hotel_description b ON a.id = b.hotel_id
WHERE a.hotel_code = 'IDJKT_00001'

SELECT c.image_title, c.image_url
FROM hotel a
JOIN hotel_image c ON a.id = c.hotel_id
WHERE a.hotel_code = 'IDJKT_00001'
```

At the moment you have a hotel, you join this hotel with the description table. the description table has 7 rows for this hotel, so at this point you will have 7 rows. Then you join these 7 rows with the image table, you have at least 4 images from what i can see on the image. this means you will get 7*4=28 rows.

Comment: that is the query you had without the a.id, b.id and c.id, i asked if you could add them so we can see those as well. and like i said turning it into an sql fiddle would make this much easier ^^

Comment: the resulst you show imply that there are multiple hotel description entrees for one hotel, also there are multiple images for one hotel, this will of course give multiple entrees as a result. what kind of result did you expect?

Comment: @mosestoh i tried explaining what is going on, don't know if it's clear?